# detox test as app loading TypeError: null is not an object 'evaluating RNGestureHandler.default.Direction'

Tags: react-native, detox

I am trying to run the initial test I set up yesterday, which was working. Today when I launch the test I get the TypeError: null is not an object 'evaluating RNGestureHandler.default.Direction' and the app will not load. react-native run-ios launches the app as expected with no issues. When I run the detox test command the app build fails.

Android is behaving properly.

I've tried linking manually in XCode. I've tried clearing the cache. I've removed and installed the RN modules. I've added the podfile reference manually.

I'm trying to figure out why the app will load with react-native run-ios but the detox test app load fails. Could it be loading a different build? Is there a file somewhere Detox saves an iOS build folder? I thought it uses the value in the binaryPath.  I can't figure out why it worked yesterday but not today.

Here's the package.json:

````
"test-runner": "jest",
"configurations": {
"ios.sim.debug": {
"binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app",
"build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Debug -
sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
"type": "ios.simulator",
"device": {
"type": "iPhone 11"
}
},
"android.emu.debug": {
"binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
"build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
"type": "android.emulator",
"device": {
"avdName": "Nexus_5X_API_26"
}
},
"android.emu.release": {
"binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
"build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..",
"type": "android.emulator",
"device": {
"avdName": "Nexus_5X_API_26"
}
}
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok Figured it out.  Posting it here for anyone who has this issue too.

I removed the `ios/build` folder and did a new build with Detox:

```
detox build -c ios.sim.debug
```

And now everything is working again on iOS.